# VBA Trying to search for string, use range to copy the information in that column's values and output it to a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have many Excel documents (containing about a page of information, A-H columns and 1-25rows give or take a few) in a folder titled "Progress".

In one Excel document, I am trying to search for a particular column title "Tool Cutter" and take everything listed in that column, copy it, and output it to a separate spreadsheet (all of the tools are separated by a semicolon if that helps at all).

I am trying to write a program which goes into the "Progress" folder and will loop through opening each file, copying the "Tool Cutter" values I need, outputing it to a separate Excel spreadsheet I've titled "MasterList.xlsm", closing the file, and working through all of the files in that folder until there are none left.

It would be helpful if the "MasterList.xlsm" file could have Name in column 1 and Tools in column 2.

Any advice would be very helpful! I am not an expert in VBA.

What I have been trying:
Methods with AdvancedFilter, CopyToRange, SearchString...
All of the information I am trying to grab is in a column between titles "tools" and "general setup" so this code has been somewhat helpful:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer

    'Speed up process by not updating the screen
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

Set Sht = ActiveSheet

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) <> "xls" And LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) <> "xls" Then
        Else
            'print file name
            Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name

        End If

        'Range("J1").Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Windows("masterfile.xlsm").Activate
        'Range("D2").Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next objFile

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**The document (image attached) is not formatted them same way every time, depending on the info available sometimes column number or row number is different.

Comment: What's the connection to google-apps-script here?

Comment: Similar application of automating workflow, uses Macro, Java can be very similar to VBA, etc. Another line in the water I guess. Like I said, any advice is helpful! Sorry if that tag made it more confusing.

Comment: I kind of have an idea of what you're trying to do. It looks like you're on the right track. Could you explain your data setup a little better? I'm wondering if tools are listed across multiple columns or multiple rows. Also, is General Setup a different column or is it in the same column, but a different row? You can upload a screenshot to Imgur and reply with the link, that would help a lot. I'm assuming you want to grab the range psuedo code: `Range(ToolsCol & "2:" & GenCol - 1 & LastToolsRow`

Comment: A couple of questions. In this line `Do While .Range("A" & p) <> ""` aren't you assuming that the word "tools" was found in column A or that column A always has an entry for each entry under the "tools" heading? Secondly, you don't seem to be using the `curRow` variable inside this loop. Is it needed?

Comment: To @user1274820 , the information is sensitive so I'll put up a screenshot of the general layout.

To ChipsLetten , the range for column "A" lists numbers 1 to n depending on how many tools are in the list. Thus if a number exists in that column, the program knows to fill a tool in that same row a few columns over. The curRow variable is used to continue down the column of the "Tools" list until the list of tools that are to be input in the column is empty. 

My code is very choppy, just playing with things. I'll add it above.

Comment: Since no one has answered I will undelete my previous answer. I got super busy and didn't have a chance to test all of the code, but hopefully it will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to get the last row/column - much faster than looping:

```
Function getLastRow(sheet As String, Col As Variant) As Integer
getLastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Sheets(sheet).Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function getLastCol(sheet As String, row As Variant) As Integer
getLastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, Sheets(sheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

The full version of these functions lets you specify the workbook to check

*(which is important when you are opening multiple workbooks like you plan to)*

```
Function GetLastCol(Row As Variant, Optional Sheet As String, Optional WB As Variant) As Integer
    If IsMissing(WB) Then
        If Sheet = vbNullString Then
            GetLastCol = Cells(Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Else
            GetLastCol = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(Row, Sheets(Sheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End If
    Else
        If Sheet = vbNullString Then
            GetLastCol = WB.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, WB.ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Else
            GetLastCol = WB.Sheets(Sheet).Cells(Row, WB.Sheets(Sheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function GetLastRow(Col As Variant, Optional Sheet As String, Optional WB As Variant) As Integer
    If IsMissing(WB) Then
        If Sheet = vbNullString Then
            GetLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        Else
            GetLastRow = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(Sheets(Sheet).Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Else
        If Sheet = vbNullString Then
            GetLastRow = WB.ActiveSheet.Cells(WB.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        Else
            GetLastRow = WB.Sheets(Sheet).Cells(WB.Sheets(Sheet).Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

If you have a square block of data like most excel sheets, you can also use:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

The benefit of using these functions is that you can use it like:

```
Range("A1:A" & GetLastRow("A"))
```

The rest of your find code looks okay.

Here is a function to find all files in a folder.

It returns a collection of path names that you can iterate through using a `For Each` loop as demonstrated below:

```
Private Function GetFiles(Path As String, Optional Extension As String = "*") As Collection
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim FilesReturned As Collection
    Set FilesReturned = New Collection
    Dim Files, File
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Files = objFSO.GetFolder(Path).Files
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Files Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    For Each File In Files
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(Path & File.Name)) Like UCase(Replace(Extension, ".", "")) Then
                FilesReturned.Add (Path & IIf(Right(Path, 1) = "\", "", "\") & File.Name)
        End If
    Next File
    Set GetFiles = FilesReturned
End Function
```

You can use this with a `For Each` loop to loop through each workbook.

You can open them using Workbooks.Open and use your find code like so:

(*This code should go in the master sheet*)

```
Sub GetTools()

Dim Files as Collection
On Error Resume Next
Set Files = GetFiles("C:\OurPath")
On Error GoTo 0
If Files Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Files Found!")
    Exit Sub
End If

'You can also use this to specify the extension if there are other types:
'Set Files = GetFiles("C:\OurPath","xls")

Dim ThisWb as Workbook
Set ThisWb = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each File In Files
    Workbooks.Open File, ReadOnly:=True
    'Add code to find things and copy
    'We can use this line to copy from the Open Workbook, Sheet1, Range A2-A[Lastrow]
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & GetLastRow("A","Sheet1")).Copy _
        ThisWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & GetLastRow("A","Sheet1",ThisWb) + 1)
    'to the bottom of our Master Sheet, column A
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next File
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Testing**

I have the following files in a directory:

[image: Directory]

Tools1.xls: [image: Tools1] Tools2.xlsx": [image: Tools2]

When I run the macro on my "Master":

[image: Master]

I am left with these results:

[image: Results]

Edit:

If you want to add a function to your code, treat it as a separate subroutine.

For example:

```
Sub DoThings()

    For x = 1 to 10
        MsgBox(getLastRow("Sheet1",x))
    Next x

End Sub

Function getLastRow(sheet As String, Col As Variant) As Integer
getLastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Sheets(sheet).Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: where exactly would I put the Functions? I am trying to put them in but it makes me create an end Sub and I don't think that's what I want it to do

Comment: You can add functions to any module. You can also put them in the sheet objects if needed, but it's typical to place them in modules. http://i.imgur.com/QF7o0ka.png

Comment: My code now opens multiple files in a folder through a loop. Where would I put the functions in my code? Whenever I try to put the functions in my for loop, I get the error that it wants an End Sub before the function. (I have edited my code in the original post) @user1274820

Comment: Put the functions outside of your subroutine. They should not be in the middle of the loop - rather, you call them inside the loop - they should be separate from the subroutine. See my edit

Comment: The difference between a function and a subroutine is that a function returns a value. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html